# sending one view's UISearchBar searchString to another view's UISearchBar and executing the search

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am new to coding and I've been making great progress... until now! I've been setting up an application for the iPhone but I've run into a wall.

I'm trying to send the searchString from my `HomeViewController`'s `UISearchBar` to my `tableViewController`'s `UISearchBar`, and then I want my `TableViewController`'s `UISearchBar` to automatically execute a search based upon the initial searchString, thus populating the `TableViewController`'s table with a filtered array.

When I use the home view's `searchBar`, it does push the application to the table view, however, the database's array isn't filtered. The table view does have a functional `UISearchBar` that can filter my array based upon various `searchStrings` that I feed it.

I've tried many things based upon examples I've found through google, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my relevant code. (I've left out a bit of code that I think is irrelevant to the problem at hand).

HOME VIEW CONTROLLER

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
{

NSString *pushedSearchString;    
UISearchBar *homeSearchBar;

}

@property (strong) NSString *pushedSearchString;    
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *homeSearchBar;

...    
...    
...

@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize pushedSearchString, homeSearchBar;

- (void)updateSearchString:(NSString*)aSearchString    
{    
pushedSearchString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:aSearchString];    
}    
- (void)searchBarButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar    
{    
[self updateSearchString:searchBar.text];    
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];    
TableViewController *tableViewController = [self.storyboard insantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"table"];    
table.title = @"Results";    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:table animated:YES];    
}
```

...

...

...

My `TableViewController` looks similar although it has slightly different variables. I've tried manipulating code inside the `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method, as I've seen via other posts, but nothing worked.

I would greatly appreciate any help I can get - thanks for reading this and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the property for a NSString in Tableviewcontroller.And synthesize it in .m file.And make the below change in your homeviewcontroller method.

```
- (void)searchBarButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar    
{    
[self updateSearchString:searchBar.text];    
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];    
TableViewController *tableViewController = [self.storyboard insantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"table"];
table.someString = searchBar.text;
table.title = @"Results";    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:table animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: thanks @Tendulkar, i've done as you advised - and i've also added in the `- void(viewWillAppear:(Bool)animated` method `self.theSearchBar.text = someString`. doing this, the search term carries over into the tableview's uisearchbar - but the application still requires that you manually interact with the searchBar to execute the search. i am wondering how to automatically execute the search term upon switching views. thanks!

Comment: I just figured out the fix. in the TableViewController.m I added to the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method the line of code `[self searchBarSearchButtonClicked:theSearchBar];`. I added this in addition to the line of code `self.theSearchBar.text = someString;`.